# Template function to copy two character arrays

Tags: c++

There is an old C macro that I'm trying to replace:

```
// Copy the contents of the character array b into character array a. If the source
// array is larger than the destination array, limit the amount of characters copied
#define STRCPY(a,b) if(b) strncpy(a, b, sizeof(a) < sizeof(b) ? sizeof(a) : sizeof(b))
```

I was hoping templates would help. Maybe something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
template <typename T, size_t N, typename TT, size_t M>
void scopy(T (dest[N]), const TT (src[M]))
{
    strncpy(dest, src, N < M ? N : M);
}

int main()
{
    char foo[10] = "abc";
    char bar[5] = "xyz";
    scopy(foo, bar);
}
```

gcc reports badness

Edit: My pseudo example used different sized arrays than the actual compiler error I was getting. Fixed now

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘scopy(char [5], const char [10])’
```

Comment: Is that error really from that code? Where did the `7` come from? BTW,  there is something inherently wrong in accepting `T` but using it under the assumption that it is `char`.

Comment: Open to suggestions on how verify that the type is a char.

Comment: Just let the compiler do that for you: `template <size_t N, size_t M> void scopy(char (&dst)[N], char const (&src)[M])`? Alternatively, drop the assumption and use `copy_n` or `copy` internally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need *references* to arrays, since arrays cannot be passed by value (nor would that make sense, since you actually want to modify the original array):

```
template <typename T, size_t N, typename TT, size_t M>
void scopy(T (&dest)[N], const TT (&src)[M])
{
    strncpy(dest, src, N < M ? N : M);
}
```

You should probably also assert somewhere that `sizeof(T) == 1` and `sizeof(TT) == 1`, since otherwise `strncpy` isn't going to be doing the right thing. Or, if you feel modern, replace the body with:

```
std::copy_n(src, N < M ? N : M, dst);
```

Comment: Of course, having a parameter like `char dest[100]` works fine. The issue is that the template parameter deduction rules specify that the argument type is decayed prior to deduction, *except* when the parameter is a reference.

Comment: @BrianBi: I'm not quite sure what you're referring to. The declarations `void f(char*)`, `void f(char[])` and `void f(char[10])` are all identical. The square brackets have special meaning in the function declarator. There's no "decay". (The decay happens in the *call* expression.)

Comment: You said that the reason why you need references to arrays is that arrays can't be passed by value. But this doesn't really seem to explain anything, since the declarator without the reference *still* doesn't pass the array by value, anyway. The actual reason why you need the reference is to prevent decay in the "call expression", as you put it. (If decay occurs then the extent cannot be deduced.)